# Can not convert from NumSharp.NDArray to OpenCvSharp.InputArray

Tags: python, c#, numpy, opencv

I am trying to convert my Python code to C#. I am using NumSharp and OpenCvSharp in Visual Studio 2019. The python code work without errors but I am getting in travel with this part of the code :

```
var  kernel = np.ones((9, 9), np.uint8);
Cv2.MorphologyEx(frame2, opening_ori,  MorphTypes.Open, kernel);
```

the error is in the

> kerner

: **Can not convert from NumSharp.NDArray to OpenCvSharp.InputArray**

The Python code is:

```
kernel = np.ones((9, 9), np.uint8)
opening_ori = cv2.morphologyEx(frame2, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
```

I will appreciate any help about it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your kernel needs to be of type InputArray (which there are many implicit conversions in OpenCV, such as from Mat or MatExpr). For something simple like an 9x9 matrix of 1s, you can use the OpenCV functions to create one.

Something like this should work (untested):

```
InputArray kernel = Mat.Ones(9, 9, MatType.CV_8UC);
Cv2.MorphologyEx(frame2, opening_ori,  MorphTypes.Open, kernel);
```

Note: For more complicated marshalling, you can usually get the raw memory array from one type, and use that to create the Mat.